# I can't figure out this Tkinter error

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm using Python's Tkinter to create a GUI for a project i'm working on.

When I try to run part of the code though, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "calculator.py", line 59, in <module>
    app = Application()
  File "calculator.py", line 28, in __init__
    self.create_widgets()
  File "calculator.py", line 45, in create_widgets
    self.special_chars.create_button(char, self.add_char_event(special_characters[char]))
  File "calculator.py", line 20, in create_button
    self.button_list += Button(self, text = txt, command = fcn)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/
lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1206, in cget
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects
```

The problem is that I can't find the file that the error message references; my `python2.7/lib-tk` folder only contains complied versions (.pyo and .pyc) of Tkinter.

Is there a way to figure out what's going wrong?

Here's the source of calculator.py

```
from Tkinter import *
from exp import full_eval
from maths import special_characters

class special_char_frame(LabelFrame):
    def __init__(self, master = None, text = 'Special Characters'):
        LabelFrame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid()
        self.button_list = []
    def create_button(self, txt, fcn):
        self.button_list += Button(self, text = txt, command = fcn)
        self.button_list[-1].grid(row = 0)


class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master = None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid()
        self.create_widgets()
    def create_widgets(self):
        ## equation entry pane
        self.text_entry = Entry(self, width = 100)
        self.text_entry.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
        self.text_entry.bind('<KeyPress-Return>', self.calculate)
        ## result pane
        self.result = StringVar()
        self.result_label = Label(self, textvariable = self.result, wraplength = 815, justify = LEFT)
        self.result_label.grid(row = 1, column = 0, columnspan = 2, sticky = W)
        self.result.set('')
        ## calculate button
        self.calc_button = Button(self, text = 'Calculate', command = self.calculate)
        self.calc_button.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
        ## special character button pane
        self.special_chars = special_char_frame(self)
        for char in special_characters:
            self.special_chars.create_button(char, self.add_char_event(special_characters[char]))
        self.special_chars.grid(column = 0, columnspan = 2, row = 2)
    def calculate(self, event = None):
        try:
            self.result.set(full_eval(self.text_entry.get()))
        except Exception as error:
            raise
            #self.result.set(str(error))
        self.text_entry.select_range(0, END)
    def add_char_event(self, char):
        def add_char(self = self, event = None):
            self.text_entry.insert(INSERT, char)
        return add_char

app = Application()
app.master.title('Calculator')
app.mainloop()
```

`full_eval` is a function for evaluating mathematical expressions.

`special_characters` is a dict containing special characters and their explanations.  For now it's just `special_characters = {'imaginary unit' : u'\u2148'}`

Comment: Post the full traceback.

Comment: Also, post the rest of your code, or at least the code run up to the point where the problem happens.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams there it is ... but i'm more interested in learning how to figure out the error than learning what the actual error is.  Like what's the deal with the error message referencing a file that I can't find?

Comment: The file doesn't necessarily exist... you figure out the error by seeing where you're using an `int` where it should be a string or a `str` where you should be using an integer.

Comment: How can you expect to figure out the error if you can't find out where the error is? Anyways, post calculator.py.

Comment: @Ignacio I was thinking it would be easier to locate the error if I could look in the Tkinter.py file, no?  Which is why I was perplexed that it doesn't appear to exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I missed this the first time, but the issue is actually that you are trying to add a Button to a list:

```
self.button_list += Button(self, text = txt, command = fcn)
```

If you simply wrap the Button in brackets, the error goes away (which makes sense because you are supposed to be able to add two lists):

```
self.button_list += [Button(self, text = txt, command = fcn)]
```

---

**ORIGINAL ATTEMPT**

My guess:

`special_characters` is a dictionary. It has key-value mappings where the values are `int`s. Then, when used in `self.text_entry.insert(INSERT, char)`, text_entry is trying to insert an int into a str and causing the above error. The simple solution: wrap `char` with `str` in `add_char`.

```
def add_char_event(self, char):
    def add_char(self = self, event = None):
        self.text_entry.insert(INSERT, str(char))
    return add_char
```

Your other option is to wrap str around the `special_characters` lookup:

```
    for char in special_characters:
        self.special_chars.create_button(char,
             self.add_char_event(str(special_characters[char])))
```

Comment: when I tried the second idea, I got a different error: `self.special_chars.create_button(char, self.add_char_event(str(special_characters[char])))
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2148' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)`

Comment: so i just changed the `u'u\2148'` to a normal character (`'i'`) to get rid of the error, and the first error (about concatenating int and str) came up again

Comment: I just got everything running by adding the brackets.

Comment: splendid, thanks!  So as I was asking in the other comments, can you tell why the traceback references a file that doesn't seem to exist?